# will ng disabled prevent submitting form elements

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

As said in HTML Forms, all the disabled form fileds will be prevented from submitting on Form Submit.

In Angular JS if i used ng-disable for an Input field, then do the field gets really submitted if I do this way

```
<form>
 <input type="text" ng-disabled="true" name="foo">
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

If not why? feels like silly but bit confused on the subject

Comment: I dont know.. you are asking a question or answering yourself !

Comment: Edited my question, think's I had expressed clearly now !!

Answer (score 0):

The library sets the boolean `disabled` attribute on the element, if `ng-disabled` has a value which is truthy. I believe the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) is quite clear on the subject. The part I referred to:

> The HTML specification does not require browsers to preserve the values of boolean attributes such as disabled. (Their presence means true and their absence means false.) If we put an Angular interpolation expression into such an attribute then the binding information would be lost when the browser removes the attribute. The ngDisabled directive solves this problem for the disabled attribute. This complementary directive is not removed by the browser and so provides a permanent reliable place to store the binding information.

Answer (score 0):

your example

```
<form>
 <input type="text" ng-disabled="true" name="foo">
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

You are setting `ng-disabled` to `true` so it adds `disabled` attribute to the form, if you submit the form, As said in HTML Forms, all the disabled form fileds will be prevented from submitting on Form Submit, so

1. with normal form submit, i.e in html way `type="submit"`, the input values will be only posted through the form if the value inside `ng-disabled` is set to false or returns false.
2. in angularjs `ng-submit` same thing happens, i.e. the form is posted just that a method can be called after the form is submitted.

Comment: Can i have any referrence for your point-2, First point is obvious with HTML forms. Anyway thanks.

Comment: To clarify my point no-2: angular does nothing out of the box while submitting the form. What applies to html forms while submitting also applies to ng submit. Just that the disabled attribute is dynamically added or removed from the elements based on the value of ngDisabled